# Remove invalid characters from message sent to AWS/Amazon SQS

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

**Context:** 
Amazon SQS has a constraint on ranges of characters it will accept when a message passed in the argument to the `sqsClient.sendMessage(...)`.
(Mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html)).

Exerpt from the above link:

`A message can include only XML, JSON, and unformatted text. The following Unicode characters are allowed:`

`#x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF`

`Any characters not included in this list will be rejected.`

**Question:**
For now, we know offending characters are present in the message json which is sent as a message, so we filter them out by 
`message_json.replaceAll("\uffff", "");` and this works fine. (where '\uffff' is the java representation of the xFFFF/U+FFFF character).

However, instead of only doing for the xFFFF character, I want to do this for the entire ranges mentioned above(`#x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF`) but how do I construct a clause that can take range of characters without running replace on each one?

Comment: Clarifying the question: I want to do the replace on all the invalid characters mentioned above. I am not asking about multiple occurrences of the same character.

Comment: Are you sending JSON or XML messages, or plain text? Most of these characters are already invalid in JSON/XML - they will probably be rejected when you try to parse the message. Otherwise, you can create a character class in your regex using square brackets - include all the valid characters in the class, then negate the class by putting `[^` at the beginning.

Comment: It is a json string which contains this character. Yes, i was wondering how a regex class/or any construct that can take ranges such as [\u20 - \ud7ff ]. That is the main question.

Comment: What have you tried in terms of construction? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer was right in front of me. For some reason, I had assumed that the character classes of a regex will not accept these escaped chars such as `[\ufffd-\uffff]` inside `message_json.replaceAll("[\ufffd-\uffff]", " ");`

This works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and used this regex

````
/([^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}])/u```
````